# Rails model structures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I saw some threads on this already on Stack, but wanted a little more clarification.

I have seen many apps where there is a product model and category category model.  This is a has and belongs to many association, or a has_many through association.

I have also seen many apps where there is a user model and an email_address model.  Email_address belongs to user, but user can have many email addresses.

My question is, would there ever be a situation where you can lump all the email addresses or categories into the user and product models, respectively?  So in your user model, you will have email_one, email_two, etc?

What are the pros and cons of breaking it into different models?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attribute is simple, it's almost certainly best to keep it in a single model - you can even serialize the attribute so that it takes, for example, and array of email_addresses.  BUT (big but) you may well want to add a lot more information to an email address - which one is the primary one, when was it last profiled, email last sent to .. etc etc.  This of course is much easier to handle if you have a separate email address model.  So perhaps the question is really 'when should i use serialized attributes?'.  My own answer would be 'only if I'm sure that I am storing something in that field that I never want to add further attributes to'.  Usually that means it is something pretty peripheral to the main application, and about which no-one cares very much ...

Comment: And remember if you serialise an array of e.g. email addresses into a single field, it then becomes harder to reliably find a user based on a single email address

Comment: Thanks @Gareth. It makes sense then to separate things into their own models to provide for the most flexibility.

Comment: @chrispanda, is it possible to have two or more fields in the user model for example for email addresses?  Like instead of storing it in one field or in a separate email model, you can have primary_email, secondary_email, tertiary_email, etc. attributes in the user model?  My concern with something like that for example is the difficulty in authenticating the user with email and password in separate models. Thanks.

Comment: well, it's possible, but I can't think of good reasons for doing it.  If you want to authenticate with email and password, then you probably want a primary_email field to do that.  The other fields might as well be serialized - the advantage of doing it that way is that you are not constrained to a fixed number of alternate email addresses - though as Gareth pointed out, this makes it harder to search for a user based on their email address